# Error in download file using powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

Am trying to download sqlserver express 2012 on my EC2 instance.following sample given [here](https://teusje.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/download-file-with-powershell/).
this is my script:

```
$storageDir = "C:\download"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29062"
$file = "$storageDir"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
```

C:\download is where i want the downloaded file to be save.
but i keep getting this error:

```
 Exception calling"DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s):"An exception occurred 
during a webClient request."
At line:1 chart:1
+$wc.DownloadFile($url,$output)
+$webclient.DownloadFile($url,"file)
+CategoryInfo                  :NotSpecified:(:)[], MethodInvocationException
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong. 
I have tried to download from my pc and copying to aws vis rdc but takes hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to the DownloadFile method is the path to the filename you want to use for saving the file - not the directory. You would need to change your line to:

```
$file = "$storageDir\SQLEXPRE_x64_ENU.exe"
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx